# How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2.27

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-web-services

I am working on moving an IIS server website onto an AWS Multi AZ instance. I am trying to figure out how to Manipulate the web link on Apache.

I referred to this link but have not been able to solve the problem: 
[How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2#comment32529587_869092)

When I type in:

```
mod_rewrite
```

I get this error:

```
bash: mod_rewrite: command not found
```

This line is not commented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.s
```

Also, when I try to restart Apache using the following command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I receive this error:

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

Which I have read that it might have to do something with CentOS.

I am using Amazon Linux AMI release 2012.03.

How can I get the mod_rewrite command to work?

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is not really related to programming, but more to server management. You probably have better luck on ServerFault to get this question answered.